# Evaluate $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\large(\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\large)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I though you could approach it by getting the denominator the same so the but that didn't help. I don't know how to approach problems with subtraction

Comment: This is a telescopic series

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: Or else note that $\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a $\displaystyle \sum$ summation, especially if you aren't as comfortable with them, it's a good idea to write out the first few terms explicitly.  Here are the first four terms:

$$
\frac12 - \frac14 \quad+\quad \frac14 - \frac18 \quad+\quad \frac18 - \frac{1}{16} \quad+\quad \frac{1}{16} - \frac{1}{32}
$$

What do you notice?

Comment: oh i see. the ratio seems to be $1/4n$... so $1/4 < 1$ so it converges. and thus we use $a/1-r$ to find the sum

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Take the sum from $n=0$ to $n=5$, and see what happens.

Comment: sum it to n and then lim n approaches to infinity